# Which series is growing more?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am a c# .NET programmer with a math question

I have a list of numbers.  Imagine they were test-scores of a set of students in different schools.

Is there a formula to will tell me which of these students is improving the most, the "most improved student"? I'd like to rank the students best to worst.

```
 John: 45, 65, 67, 65, 56, 80
 Sall: 78, 88, 89, 89, 90, 78, 88, 89
 Samy: 56, 78, 89, 87, 87
```

Comment: If would depend on you definition of improving. How about numerical derivatives of the test results?

Comment: Improving would be that their trend of marks has gone up the most. A kid who does 50->60->80 is a better improved student than 80->81->85

Comment: Well, then this is a good way to do it. You have $n$ lists (representing the test results of each student) like $[r_{1,j}1,r_{2,j},..,r_{m,j}]$. $r_{i,j}i$ is the $i$-th test result of student $j$. The $i$-th difference $$\Delta r_j(i)=r_{i+1,j}-r_{i,j}$$ describes the improvement student $j$ made from the $i$-th result to the $i+1$-th result. The list $[\Delta r_j(1),\Delta r_j(2),\Delta r_j(m-1)]$ shows the improvements of student $j$ throughout the tests. Now you can find the maxima of all the differences and this would be the most improving student. Though there might be multiple maxima.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple and efficient way is computing for each student the average of the successive "improvements" to get an idea of how much the score of the student has improved so far.

Formally, if $\langle x_0,\dots,x_{n-1} \rangle$ are the scores of the student, you compute:
$$\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i = 1}^{n-1} (x_i - x_{i-1}).$$
(Note that, of course, you need at least two scores).

From your example you would get:

```
John: ((65-45) + (67-65) + (65-67) + (56-65) + (80-56)) / 5 = 7
Sall: ((88-78) + (89-88) + (89-89) + (90-89) + (78-90) + (88-78) + (89-88)) / 7 = 1.58
Samy: ((78-56) + (89-78) + (87-89) + (87-87)) / 4 = 7.75
```

So Sall has not improved much (the scores are high but quite similar), whereas Samy and John have improved much more.

Comment: This gives only one value for all the tests. Someone could do really bad on the first few test, then score much higher in the next few (i.e. improve) then score the same on further tests (i.e. not improve any further). Your test would yield that this student is improving, even though he is not (anymore).

Comment: Yes, of course, but the question is a bit vague on this: "which of these students is *improving* the most, the '*most improved* student'?". Certainly Samy is not currently improving that much, but she has improved a lot, so she could qualify as the "most improved student".

Comment: Agreed, the highest scoring (=best?) student does not necessarily have to be improving the most.

Comment: I have made a few changes to reflect this idea.

Comment: Does this pattern have a name? If so, I can look around for a Math tool which has it and can feed in the values. Thanks!!